# populate a list once

Tags: list, clojure, datomic

Using datomic and clojure I query a database and get a list of nine elements.

I would like to draw these nine elements on the page, and at this point they are guaranteed to be distinct elements.

However, every time I call the function, it redoes the query, returns a new list, and then gets an element from the new list.  This is very inefficient and also introduces the possibility of duplicates.

I would like to memoize this list and have it be nth-indexable.  Suggestions and ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling "the function", you should only call it if you have not called it already. If you call it, make sure to store the result. If you don't call it, look up the result.

`memoize` (http://crossclj.info/fun/clojure.core/memoize.html) might help you to achieve that. Depending on your cache requirements, you might want to study its implementation and implement something more suitable.

You might want to refer to https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize for more sophisticated memoization needs on the serverside.

Any list is nth-indexable with O(n). For O(log 32 n) performance, create a vector from it using `vec`.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up learning about http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay delay via the #Clojure freenode channel.  When one derefs the fxn it runs the body once and caches the result; future derefs will get the cached result.  Using a let over a delay  (let [results (delay (query ...))]  ___ @result ) helped me to achieve what I wanted.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Delay is useful if the function takes no arguments. I am not convinced by your example that you have achieved memoization because a new delay is created everytime your let form is evaluated. Notice that I have added a link to core.memoize to the answer.